# how to use move_upload file function in my code undefined index with file uploading?

Tags: php

I am new in php and mysql,want to  file upload with three input and also move upload file in my project folder. this is my code.

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))


    $birthcertificate  = $_FILES['file1']['name'];  
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];  
    if(isset($birthcertificate)){
        if(!empty($birthcertificate)){      
            $location = '.images/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$birthcertificate)){
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        }       
    }  else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }

$sql = "insert into tabel(......)values($birh..,$pclaa..,$transfer..);
```

error:

> undefined index and warning in move_upload file

Comment: Please show the actual error report message, don't paraphrase it, so we know exactly where is the problem.

Comment: Please add full code and the error

Comment: Do you have this html into your code: `<input name="file1" id="file1" type="file">`? Have you tried with full path? `$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/";`?

Comment: <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Comment: <p>Birth Certificate</p>
 <input type="file" name="file1"/>
 <p>Previous Class Mark-Sheet</p>
 <input type="file" name="file2">
 <p>Previous School Transfer Certificate</p>
  <input type="file" name="file3">

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     $birthcertificate=$_POST['file1'];
 $pclassmarksheet=$_POST['file2'];
     $transfercertificate=$_POST['file3'];